# How to send multiple selected values to database query in android?

Tags: android

In my project previously I kept radio buttons and if any of the radio button(subjects) is selected I sent that particular id 
to the query dynamically. But now I need to keep check boxes instead of radio buttons, which means multiple selection is possible.
So if multiple checkboxes are selected how can I send the id's to the query to retrieve the data.

select * from mytable where my_id = 92

In the above query in place of 92 I am passing the value dynamically. But now if I select more than one checkbox then how to send the values dynamically to the query 
and how to display the data from the database table.

Anybody help me regarding this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id IN (92,93,94)`, adding any number of id's in the parenthesis.

Now the interesting part comes into how to build that string dynamically. My suggestion would be to build a string using an iteration over your list of id's.

```
String whereClause = "my_id IN (";

for (String id : idList) {

    if (whereClause.charAt(whereClause.length - 1) != "(") {
        whereClause += ",";
    }

    whereClause += id;
}        

whereClause += ")";
```

Once you have this string built you can pass it into your db query method as the `selection` paramater.

Answer (score 0):

How about `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE my_id = 92 OR my_id = 93` ?

You should also use the API provided with Android, like this:

```
    final Cursor c = mDb.query(true, "mytable",
            new String[] { "name, description, title" }, // columns
            "myid = ? OR myid = ?", // WHERE
            new String[] { "92", "93" }, // WHERE args
            null, // GROUPBY ***
            null, // HAVING ***
            null, // ORDER BY ***
            null); // LIMIT
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response..For example I have 8 checkboxes,say first I selected 1st 4 and again I unselected those and selected next four checkboxes. So now only the last four chk box id's which I selected should go dynamically to the query. How can I do that? If I give as u say by using or symbol then all the id's data will be displayed na..